# Restful Web services using ORDS 3.0 for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am new to using AngularJS with webservices created using ORDS 3.0. I have created some web services using ORDS 3.0 in sql developer and using the new API APEX_JSON for crunching json data in PLSQL. Right now My Dababase is having only one schema and when I am using the web service, it is pointing to this schema by default. If I have multiple schemas enabled for rest services and all those schemas have same table for which I am using the web service, how the url will decide to point to which schema.

Thanks in advance,